# Is there any way to get redshift to work?

Tags: display, xorg

I'm a fan of the [f.lux](http://justgetflux.com/) program but I couldn't find any way to install it on the arm architecture. However, there is an alternative called [Redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/).

Redshift installed fine; however, when I run it, it doesn't seem to have any effect, I am running the following as a test:

```
pi@blackpi ~ $ redshift -l 40:75 -b 0.1 -g 0.5 -o 
Gamma ramp size too small: 0
Failed to start adjustment method randr.
Trying next method...
Using method `vidmode'.
```

Then it kicks me back to the console. No matter what input commands I try, it doesn't seem to change the screen color or brightness at all.

Comment: Absence of “blue filter” functionality on rpi is a serious usability issue. My lame temporary solution for passive user scenario is window overlay, e.g. terminal with red orange color background, semi-transparent by e.g. `transset 0.75` after launching `xcompmgr`.

Answer (score 4):

The closed source graphics driver doesn't expose gamma ramps, which are what redshift relies on.  To get gamma ramps, you'll need to switch to the open source graphics driver.

Using raspi-config (assuming you're using Raspbian), enable the experimental OpenGL driver (in native mode, not "firmware KMS") and reboot, at which point redshift should work.

Comment: I can confirm that the GL driver that Raspbian (now Raspberry Pi OS) includes *doesn't* resolve this issue.  The driver can be selected within `raspi-config`, however upon rebooting the Pi and restarting redshift (which is running), the visual effects (colour temperature, brightness, gamma) are not produced.  I have also tried this by installing other Debian distros on the Pi, where I have confirmed redshift to work on those distros but on other architectures, i386, amd64.  I have included the raspbian repository to enable the GL KMS driver, but still to no avail.

Comment: This seems to be outdated; the described option is now longer available in raspi-config.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, but maybe soon (~2017).

With the new experimental OpenGL driver in Raspbian, it may be possible for Redshift to work.

Comment: I can confirm this doesn't work.  Please see my comment on the post above.